Trying to Open a .dotx Word Template File Opens a Blank Document
Issue: I want to edit an existing Word template *.dotx file, and I am unable to.
What I did: I created a *.dotx file by right-clicking on "This Document's Style Set" in the Design tab > Save > Save as Type > Word Templates ( *.dotx)
Note: I did it that way because:

from an existing there is no "Save As" available (see image 1)

from a blank document, there is no "save as a specific file type" available to me (see image 2)


What I tried: When I try to open an existing Word template *.dotx file by double clicking in Windows 11 Explorer, it opens a blank document with no custom styles saved.
When I try File > Open in an existing Word .docx document, there is no option to open by type, and when I navigate to the *.dotx file location, there are no *.dotx files displayed - only .docx files.
(Note: There is a similar question on 4/21/22 but that solution did not solve my problem)

It'd be good to link to that "similar question"

[Quick] Style Sets are .dotx files created by the Save Style Set command found on the Design tab have no textual content. Here is my article on the Microsoft Answers site about these. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/quick-style-sets-and-word-themes-in-microsoft-word/444d4195-a28a-43bb-b035-facd84f7bd44. If you saved such a template, you can, in any document or template apply it from the Design tab. The only customized styles that get stored in such a template are those marked to be in the [Quick] Styles Gallery.

I'll try to answer the question both directly and indirectly:

Double-clicking the .dotx opens a new document based on the template, that's what it's supposed to do. This is the way to create new documents based on the template. (Why it is "with no custom styles saved" is likely because of the way you saved the template, that it didn't save the things you wanted to)
You can edit the template itself using one of the following:

Right-click the .dotx file (in Windows Explorer) and choose Open from the context menu (and not the first option, which is New)
In Word (from the welcome screen or an open document) File > Open does allow you to open .dotx files, if you don't see it try to press Browse and ensure you have All Word Documents selected there:



To save an open file as a template, you can certainly use the Save As:

The reason you don't have a Save As option (and neither do you have a Save option) for that specific document likely has to do with where it saved on. Simply do Save a Copy and save it to yourself and then do Save As > .dotx
The blank doc certainly has an option to save as specific type, it's just part of the same Save As option. Press that and then select the .dotx type:




